# Django join multiple tables

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have the following three models. (I have removed unnecessary fields for clarity)

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class MRFDetails(models.Model):
    mrf_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomerDetails)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    machine_no = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class MRFStatus(models.Model):
    mrf_no = models.ForeignKey(MRFDetails)
    worker_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to get the result as it's expected to be given from the following SQL query. Simply to get name form product table for the values I get from MRFStatus.

```
SELECT 
 `SandD_mrfstatus`.`mrf_no_id`, 
 `SandD_mrfdetails`.`mrf_no`, 
 `SandD_mrfdetails`.`product_id_id`, 
`SandD_product`.`product_id`, `SandD_product`.`name`, 
`SandD_product`.`end_product_name` 
FROM `SandD_mrfstatus` 
INNER JOIN `SandD_mrfdetails` 
ON ( `SandD_mrfstatus`.`mrf_no_id` = `SandD_mrfdetails`.`mrf_no` ) 
INNER JOIN `SandD_product` 
ON ( `SandD_mrfdetails`.`product_id_id` = `SandD_product`.`product_id` ) 
WHERE `SandD_mrfstatus`.`status` = 0
ORDER BY `SandD_mrfstatus`.`status` ASC, 
 `SandD_mrfstatus`.`modified_datetime` DESC
```

This is what I have tried

```
gg = MRFStatus.objects.all().filter(Q(status__contains=0)).order_by('status','-modified_datetime').select_related()
```

How can I get the values that are there in MRFDetails and Product.

```
print gg.values()
```

gives the values related to MRFStatus table only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to get values from reference table use double underscore `__`, for example

```
MRFStatus.objects.filter(status=0).values(
    'mrf_no__mrf_no', 'mrf_no__product_id__name', ''
    ).order_by('status', '-modified_datetime')
```

Comment: Why did you put order_by after values? What if I use `gg.values('mrf_no__mrf_no', 'mrf_no__product_id__name')` for the same statement I used in gg?